# Python3 from bash invalid syntax

Tags: python

I have a python function that I want to exec from bash.
With Python 2 it works

```
$ python2 -c "import bech32; print bech32.bech32_create_checksum('tb', [0, 3] )"
[11, 18, 12, 1, 31, 6]
```

But I have an error syntax with python3

```
$ python -c "import bech32; print bech32.bech32_create_checksum('tb', ['0, 3'] )" 
  File "<string>", line 1
    import bech32; print bech32.bech32_create_checksum('tb', ['0, 3'] )
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

my python version is:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.7
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it even points to the place where the error is. In python3, `print` is a function so should be invoked with parentheses: `python3(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

`print()` is a function in Python 3, not part of syntax. That's why you need parentheses there.